# Popup window not scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this is probably a basic question, but I've tried every solution out there and I can't seem to get my popup window to scroll vertically.

So I have a 'p' element that an individual can click on and show several reviews. The window pops open, however, the text within the popup window extends beyond the bottom without it being scrollable.

Any help to get the window scrollable is appreciated.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p id="myBtn">See what our customers are saying</p>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to add an specific height in your `modal-content` class (50% for example):

https://jsfiddle.net/8p0moxjz/

Comment: Nice to help you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.close{
  position:fixed;
        position: fixed;
    right: 70px;
    top: 115px;
}
.modal-content{
 height:100px;
 overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<p id="myBtn">See what our customers are saying</p>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <p>...</p>
     <p>...</p>
     <p>...</p>
     <p>...</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

is this right ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow-y:scroll;` to your `modal-content` css. This will allow scrolling along the y-axis (vertically).

Answer (score 0):

[Modal scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/1dg6beok/)

Maybe this fiddle can help you.

I just added `height` into 'modal-header' and 'modal-content'.

Also move `border` from 'modal-content' into 'modal'.

If you add 'modal header' class, you can see close button always.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by just adding a specific height to the 'modal-content' class.

Comment: @mur7ay Yeah, I've seen fiddle of @GilbertoSanchez already. What I just wanna show you is when you scroll, `close button` will be scrolled same as content in modal, so seperating content and header can make fixed button. :)